# AEM - I/O Exception Connection refused

Tags: java, maven, aem

I am new to AEM. I created sample project using maven.I have followed the below site for reference.
http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/adobe-aem-cq5-tutorials/create-aem-multi-module-project/
But I am getting the below Error.

```
       [INFO] --- content-package-maven-plugin:0.5.1:install (install-custom-package) @ aemtuto.ui.apps ---
     [INFO] Installing aemtuto.ui.apps (D:\eclipse-new\aemtuto\ui.apps\target\aemtuto.ui.apps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip) to http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service.jsp
     [INFO] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
     [INFO] Retrying request
     [INFO] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
     [INFO] Retrying request
     [INFO] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
     [INFO] Retrying request
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Reactor Summary:
     [INFO] 
     [INFO] aemtuto ............................................ SUCCESS [  0.624 s]
     [INFO] aemtuto - Core ..................................... SUCCESS [  3.889 s]
     [INFO] aemtuto - UI apps .................................. FAILURE [  6.254 s]
     [INFO] aemtuto - UI content ............................... SKIPPED
     [INFO] aemtuto - Integration Tests Bundles ................ SKIPPED
     [INFO] aemtuto - Integration Tests Launcher ............... SKIPPED
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [INFO] Total time: 13.524 s
     [INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-11T18:27:30+05:30
     [INFO] Final Memory: 41M/526M
     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.day.jcr.vault:content-package-maven-plugin:0.5.1:install (install-custom-package) on project aemtuto.ui.apps: Connection refused: connect -> [Help 1]
     [ERROR] 
     [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
     [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: is aem up and running on your local machine? can you open http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/ on a browser?

Comment: No I am getting "This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect".

Comment: Could you please correct me if anything is missed here. I  just followed this site. http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/adobe-aem-cq5-tutorials/create-aem-multi-module-project/ . I am having Eclipse,Apache maven ,Java 1.8 and then installed AEM developer tool in eclipse.

Comment: your maven build is trying to install the package on http://localhost:4502, but no AEm instance is running on http://localhost:4502, you should either have the deployment step removed (by removing the autoInstallPackage profile from maven build command) or have an AEM instance setup on localhost:4502

Comment: What happens when you open `http://localhost:4502` before you attempt to deploy the package?

Comment: Highly recommend to watch youtube videos for aem installation and hello world projects in aem. Saves time rather than exploring yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> Connection refused

It comes when we run the command `mvn clean install -PautoInstallPackage` and your instance is not running.

Also, if you have mentioned some different port in **pom.xml** & AEM instance with some different port is running.

Answer (score 0):

The comments under the question helped me a lot. You should:

1. Have an AEM instance setup on localhost:4502
2. Turn on the server
3. Execute `mvn -PautoInstallPackage install` in a Terminal

Doing this I managed to upload my project into the server successfully!